# Special Characters in SQL Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, special-characters

I am concatenating four columns in my query and using this concatenated string for display. The problem is I want to separate the data from the 4 columns with '-' (a hyphen). But SQL throws an error. Suggestions?

Comment: suggestions can only be provided if you show your attempt

Answer (score 1):

Could do with viewing the SQL you are using as per the comments, but the below may help. If not I will delete.

```
DECLARE @WORD1 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @WORD2 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @WORD3 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @WORD4 VARCHAR(10)

SET @WORD1 = 'The'
SET @WORD2 = 'cat'
SET @WORD3 = 'and'
SET @WORD4 = 'dog'

SELECT @WORD1 + '-' + @WORD2 + '-' + @WORD3 + '-' + @WORD4
```